# Step 'Any Text' does not have a matching glue code after adding .feature file into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

I am new into the cucumber, but after taking an assignment and doing some initial set up I am facing an issue of warning towards used keywords of cucumber into feature file.

I went through already existing post on stack overflow but didn't get the satisfied solution to resolve hence opening this new thread.

Your help is really appreciated.

Please help me to resolve this warning as this prevent me to further execution of cucumber test.

**Eclipse Version** 
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

**Java version**
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

**Cucumber Eclipse feature Version**
Version: 0.0.22.201806032001

**Cucumber Editor Version**
0.7.6.201505100000

I am getting an warning on every line where I used keywords. e.g.

```
Given Open Firefox and Star applications
>>warning - Step 'Open Firefox and Star applications' does not have a matching glue code

When I entered valid username and credentials
>>warning - Step 'I entered valid username and credentials' does not have a matching glue code

Then user should be able to login successfully
>>warning - Step 'user should be able to login successfully' does not have a matching glue code
```

Even after - after running with 'Cucumber feature' in eclipse I am getting below snippet code which doesn't have any Regular Expression syntax. I feel this code should come with at least ^ and $.

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("Open Firefox and Star applications")
public void open_Firefox_and_Star_applications() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("I entered valid username and credentials")
public void i_entered_valid_username_and_credentials() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("user should be able to login successfully")
public void user_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Tried below:
1. I uninstall and install the cucumber twice still no luck.
2. Created a separate package and drag and drop the existing feature folder there. close all the feature file and open it again still no luck.

Your help is highly appreciate as I stuck at the start only.

Comment: Have you implemented those snippets in a class? How does your glue configuration look like? Are you able to post the relevant code so someone would be able to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Yes I have implemented the snippet into class. Though it work but due to warning's into feature file I am not getting the expected snippet which should come with reg exp. Code looks like      @When("I entered valid username and passsword")
 public void i_entered_valid_username_and_passsword() {
     driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
     driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("abcd1234");
     
 }

Comment: Can u add the cucumber options on the runner? Also add the project structure showing where the glue code is located. Guessing u are using cucumber 3, the code snippets recommended by cucumber are based on 'Cucumber Expression' rather than 'Regular Expression'. Though both are supported.https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/

Comment: import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "Feature_Test")

public class TestRunner {

}

Comment: Question is from the initial point when I added .feature file I am getting this warning.  Warning is - Step 'I Invoke the application' does not have a matching glue code. Let me know how to come out from this warning.        This is the cucumber version I used   Cucumber Eclipse feature Version: 0.0.22.201806032001

Cucumber Editor Version 0.7.6.201505100000  . Any help is really help me a lot to get rid from the issue.

Comment: import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
    @CucumberOptions(plugin  = {"pretty", "json:target/"},features = 
    "Feature_Test")

    public class TestRunner {

    }   I might be missing some jars to add OR might be required some cucumber installation. Please let me know if I am missing any installation parts.

Answer (score 0):

Please add glue attribute to your test runner.. due to which it's not getting stepdefination calss Please check below code
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/"},features = "Feature_Te"
glue={"package.stepdefination class}" // add your class path
)

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Your solution help me to generate the cucumber code by running Run As -> JUNIT Test. My question is still as it is. Can you please provide a fix to resolve the warnings which I can see into .feature file. e.g. Step 'I Invoke the application' does not have a matching glue code

Comment: If you run test runner class are you seeing any stepdefination method in console of eclipse

Comment: Yes, I can see stepdefination methods into the console of eclipse. But this didn't solve the warning message in eclipse.

Comment: Just replace that stepdefination with yours ..then it will work fine